# Nicely formatted list in android with no <ul> or <li> attributes

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Does anyone know how to format a list nicely in android (AlertDialog) specifically?

- This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.
- This is a test2. This is a test2. This is a test2. This is a test2. This is a test2. This is a test2. This is a test2. This is a test2. This is a test2. This is a test2. This is a test2.
- This is a test3. This is a test3. This is a test3. This is a test3. This is a test3. This is a test3. This is a test3. This is a test3. This is a test3. This is a test3. This is a test3.

If you look at the list above, the text stays nicely formatted to the right of the dots.

In android, since it doesnt support the `<ul>` or `<li>` attribute, it would look like this:

This is a test. This is a test. This is a test...
This is a test. This is a test...

Where the second line of the list doesnt align to the right of the dot.

Comment: Downvote?  Please explain?

Comment: You can use `RelativeLayout` to create a layout which does this.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/LeadingMarginSpan.Standard.html to your text to adjust the margin.